# Killing Process on Remote Host using Fabric

Tags: bash, ssh, fabric

I am writing a script using Fabric which needs to terminate a process remotely.

(this means that the command ends up getting executed as /bin/bash command)

The current code I have is the following:

in a kill.sh file i have

```
  /bin/kill  $(ps -ef | grep multiserver.jar | grep -v bin/sh | grep -v /bin/bash | grep -v sh | grep python  | grep -v /usr/bin/java | grep -v /usr/bin/python | grep -v sh  |  awk '{print $2}')
```

which I run in Fabric  on my remote host using the following commands

```
     local("scp "  + "kill.sh " + user +"@" + server_address + ":" + directory) 
     run ("chmod u+x kill.sh")
     run("./kill.sh")
```

However I get the following error message

```
      out: Usage:
      [] out:  kill [options] <pid> [...]


      Fatal error: run() received nonzero return code 1 while executing!

   Requested: ./kill.sh
    Executed: /bin/bash -l -c "cd ...  && ./kill.sh"
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It is quite likely that the command `ps -ef | grep multiserver.jar | grep -v bin/sh | grep -v /bin/bash | grep -v sh | grep python  | grep -v /usr/bin/java | grep -v /usr/bin/python | grep -v sh  |  awk '{print $2}'` returns nothing and therefore `kill` bails out. Do you have `pkill` available on your servers?

Comment: this command would always return the id of the grep call at the very least. and it also fails when I manually start the multiserver.jar to make sure there's something

Comment: Can you just place the entire command in `kill.sh` prior to the `kill` invocation and see what it prints out when invoked through `Fabric`. You have a `grep multiserver.jar` followed by a `grep python` in your command line. I am a bit puzzled as to what process would answer to that combination

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While solving [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17102968/reading-logs-with-fabric) with reading logs with fabric, I wrote command to kill remote processes:

```
with settings(warn_only=True):
    sudo("kill -9 `ps aux | <pipeline of greps> | awk '{print $2}'`")
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am trying to kill a sleeping celery process but above command is giving as

`Warning: sudo() received nonzero return code -1 while executing 'd=$(ps -axf | grep celery | awk '{print $1}') && echo $d && kill -9 $d '!`