# Reading logs with fabric

Tags: python, linux, shell, ssh, fabric

I'm trying to read log with **tail -f** with my fabric script:

```
@task
def log(service):
    sudo("tail -n 50 -f " + service)
```

With **-f** option you have to manually terminate **tail** by **Ctrl-C**. It doesn't work properly with fabric version (**fab log:**), **Ctrl-C** doesn't terminate remote command:

```
<remote-host>$ ps aux | grep tail
root     27314  0.0  0.0  33380  1744 ?        Ss   10:49   0:00 sudo -S -p sudo password: /bin/bash -l -c tail -n 50 -f /var/log/karma/gunicorn_gevent_error.log
root     27315  0.0  0.0   5592   584 ?        S    10:49   0:00 tail -n 50 -f /var/log/karma/gunicorn_gevent_error.log
... <they stack> ...
mezhenin 27337  0.0  0.0   7788   864 pts/8    R+   10:49   0:00 grep tail
```

What is correct way for doing things above?

Comment: How exactly do you want to read logs? Is this a periodic task you run?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680055/python-to-emulate-remote-tail-f

Comment: @moowiz2020, I want to read logs in "real time", like **tail -f**. I run this tasks manually after releases to check for problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found correct solution for this problem. I need to use `env.remote_interrupt = True`:

```
env.remote_interrupt = True
env.LOG = '<path to log>'

@task
def log():
    assert(env.remote_interrupt == True)
    with settings(warn_only=True):
        sudo("tail -n 50 -f " + env.LOG)
```

- [Example on Github](https://github.com/amezhenin/fabric_recipes/blob/master/fab_log_parallel.py)
- [My blog post (in Russian)](http://amezhenin.ru/devops/fabric-log-recipe.html)

Comment: This does not work with the latest Fabric 2. And I can't find the equivalent of remote_interrupt in the new doc. Any hint ?

Comment: @glenfant I used the following ``connections = [...];ThreadingGroup.from_connections(connections).run("tail -f log")``